# Запятая перед союзом И

Tags: пунктуация

Проконсультируйте, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед союзом И в предложении: "Если сегодня не примете лекарства, то завтра откажут почки, и Вас повезут в больницу". Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

"Если сегодня не примете лекарства, то завтра откажут почки и Вас повезут в больницу". - запятой не нужно, т.к. есть общее придаточное для двух простых, соединённых союзом И.

Запятая в ССП не ставится при наличии общего члена предложения или общего придаточного.

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном примере запятая перед И не ставится, так как подчеркивается тесная связь  предложений "завтра откажут почки и Вас повезут в больницу". Но хотелось бы дополнить ответ следующими замечаниями.

1. Я, скорее бы, определила предложение как  СПП (а не ССП), это основная структура со следующей схемой: Если ( ), то (1) и (2).
2. Предложение можно перестроить таким образом, что запятая будет ставиться: "Если сегодня не примете лекарства, то завтра откажут почки, и ТОГДА  Вас повезут в больницу". В этом случае основной структурой будет ССП:  сочинительная связь СПП и простого предложения.

Comment: Спасибо, девочки! Уразумел.

Comment: Я имела в виду ССП "завтра откажут почки и Вас повезут в больницу",запятая-то в нём, а уж если говорить обо всём предложении, то это сложное с сочинением и подчинением, а не СПП. А вот схема верна.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не ставится: общее наречие "то", констатирующее результат в двух придаточных, сообщающихся не повторяющимся союзом "и", при условии в условно-подчинённом предложении.